# Swiper pagination fractions slidesPerView 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss, swiper

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865706/swiper-slide-custom-counter-fractions

нашел готовое решение, но он работает только slidesPerView: '1',

у меня slidesPerView: '4' и breakpoints
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как правильно настроить пагинацию fractions, чтоб показал кол-во активных слайдов..

сейчас активный слайд 4 и в пагинации должен быть 4

Comment: Ни-че-го не понятно. Напишите как-то так. чтобы люди могли вас понять, а то никто просто не ответит.

Comment: изменил, может так понятнее